# Remove any occurrence of '-' from a field in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv-simple

below is my csv file,I want to remove all occurrences of - from retailer_id field and create new csv.

```
>IPAY_USER_ID,RETAILER_ID,CUST_FIRST_NAME,CUST_LAST_NAME,CUST_MIDDLE_NAME,ACTIVATION_ACTOR_ID,DATE_OF_BIRTH,GENDER,EMAIL_ID,MOBILE_NO,CUSTOMER_CATEGORY,CUST_STATUS,WALLET_TYPE,MOBILE_CIRCLE,MPIN_EXPRY_DATE,R_MOD_ID,R_MOD_TIME,R_CRE_ID,CREATION_DATE,CREATION_TIME,RETAILER_UPGRADE_REG_DATE,RETAILER_UPGRADE_REG_TIME,DEDUP2_DATE,DEDUP2_TIME,DATA_ENRICHMENT_DATE,DATA_ENRICHMENT_TIME,BLACKLIST_DATE,BLACKLIST_TIME,DEDUP3_DATE,DEDUP3_TIME,KYCN_P_Registration_Mode,CHANNEL,TD_PD_STATUS,DEFAULT_MPIN_CHANGED_OR_NOT,UPGRADE_CHANNEL,UPGRADE_STATUS,LAST_TXN_DATE,KYCF_CONVERSION_DATE,KYCF_CONVERSION_TIME,NOMINEE_NAME,RELATION_CODE,BALANCE,SEEDING AUTHORISATION ID
22909943,--,RAL,WAL,,0,08/jan/1997,,RjhL@GMAIL.COM,9923,,ACTIVE,NOKYC,RJ,2025-08-27 21:19:30,22909943,2015-11-05 17:21:17,22909943,2015-08-27,21:19:30,,,,,,,2015-11-05,17:21:17,,,SELF,WEB,,-,,PENDING,2015-08-27 21:19:30,,,,,0,
```

Comment: What do you want to replace the -- with?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{gsub(/-/, "", $2); print}' < in.csv > out.csv
```

Comment: Could you please let me know why did you use -v option in awk for this requirement ?

Comment: @siddharthajain, `-v` is to pass a variable definition, here of the Output Field Separator special variable. `-F ,` is short for `-v FS=,`. Check the awk man page for details.

Comment: to add to SC's  reply, the specific reason **why** it is necessary to set the OFS is that if you don't set it to `,` then any lines that were changed by the `gsub()` function will have the OFS changed to `awk`'s default (a single space) so it will no longer be a CSV file.  Unchanged lines will retain their original field separator (a comma)

Comment: BTW, this is not specific to `gsub()` - it will happen to any output line modified by `awk`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks,But what if  i want to remove character '-' from multiple and specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/--//g'  in.cvs > out.cvs
```

Comment: Why -i and redirect?

Comment: Although the original question isn't clear if `--` appears anywhere else, that solution risks replacing every occurrence of `--` regardless of where it resides in the file.  It would be a little safer to replace `,--,` with `,,` but even that is risky if it can appear in another field and still be required.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed` for that.

```
$ sed -r -i 's/^([0-9]+,)--,/\1,/g' file.csv
```

However, I liked the Stéphane's answer. If the `RETAILER_ID` field was the tenth field, for example, regular expressions to `sed` would be uglier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it in perl, because it allows you to be selective about named fields:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#read header row from "STDIN" (or file on command line); 
chomp ( my @header = split /,/, <> );
#print it
print join ",", @header, "\n";
#iterate STDIN or file on command line - line by line
while ( <> ) {
    #declare a row
    my %this_row;
    #strip trailing linefeed (optional, given you need to reinsert it)
    chomp;
    #select fields in this row, into named fields based on the header row. 
    @this_row{@header} = split /,/;
    #apply regex to just RETAILER_ID
    $this_row{'RETAILER_ID'} =~ s/--//;
    #print row. map is unnecessary if you've always got a full set of fields.  
    #I've included it because your sample data didn't. 
    print join ( "," , map { $_ // '' } @this_row{@header} ),"\n";
}
```

It's a bit longer than a `sed` one liner - but you could one-line-ify this if you wanted.

Because this script uses `<>` - that's the magic file handle, that reads *either* STDIN or a file specified on command line, just like `grep`, `sed` etc. would. That means though, you can do `perl -i` and inplace edit if that's your goal. Or just redirect the output.